# Probability math question, what is the chance that player 1 will win more matches than player 2?

Tags: probability

player 1 and player 2 play a series of 4 games. for each game the probability of player 1 winning is 0.5 and the probability of player 2 winning is 0.5. What are the chances that player 1 will win more of the games than player 2???

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress. What are your thoughts? What have you tried? How far could you get? Where are you stuck? This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context. Please respond by editing the question body. Clarifications don't belong in the comments

Comment: Hint: either player 1 wins more or player 2 wins more (some symmetry here) or they win an equal number

Comment: If the match is not a tie, player 1 has the same chances as player 2.  What is the probability the match is a tie?

Answer (score 0):

First, we calculate the probability they have an EQUAL number of wins. First of all, there is a $\frac1{16}$ chance for each possible win pattern because you have a $\frac12$ chance multiplied by itself $4$ times.

Now, count the number of ways to have an equal number of wins. We can choose $2$ out of the $4$ wins to be Player $1$s win, and $ {4  \choose 2 }=6$. So now we multiply $6*\frac{1}{16}$ to get $\frac38$. Since the probability they have an equal number of wins is $\frac38$, then the probaiility of having an UNEQUAL number of wins is $\frac58$.

If they have an unequal number of wins, both of them have the same chance of winning more than the other because they are equally skilled, so the probability that one player wins, specifically Player $1$, is $\frac58 /2 = \frac{5}{16}$.